# How to compare two xml with the same namespace but different prefixes using java and xmlunit

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, xmlunit

I have 2 xml files:

The problem is in attributes prefixes.

```
<element xmlns:prefix1="namespace" prefix1:attribute="some value">Some text</element>


<element xmlns:prefix2="namespace" prefix2:attribute="some value">Some text</element>
```

these two xml are the same, with the same namespace, but with different prefixes. If I compare with xmlunit -> assertion fails. How can I handle it?

in case of similar() or identical() comparison I have error:

Expected attribute name 'message:MessageNameString' but was 'null' 
Expected attribute name 'message:MessageVersion' but was 'null' 
Expected attribute name 'null' but was 'mes:MessageNameString'
Expected attribute name 'null' but was 'mes:MessageVersion'

Comment: Are you able to provide the actual XML you are testing? Even when I add attributes the "similar" check passes for me.

Comment: I can send it in e-mail. They are rather huge for stackoverflow's forms

Comment: XML defines "identicalness" — it should be possible to define a "similar" based on the XML definition of similar. e.g. `<a xmlns="foo"/>` and `<foo:a xmlns:foo="foo"/>` are semantically the same document.  Using "similar()" is problematic if child order is important (it often is).  Shucks!

Answer (score 6):

The following test passes the "similar" check but fails the "identical" check:

```
    String control = "<prefix1:element xmlns:prefix1=\"namespace\" prefix1:attribute=\"x\">Some text</prefix1:element>";
    String test = "<prefix2:element xmlns:prefix2=\"namespace\" prefix2:attribute=\"x\">Some text</prefix2:element>";
    try
    {
        Diff diff = XMLUnit.compareXML( control, test );
        assertTrue( "Similar", diff.similar() );
        assertTrue( "Identical", diff.identical() );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        fail( e.getMessage() );
    }
```

From the xmlunit API docs:

- identical: the content and sequence of the nodes in the documents are exactly the same
- similar: the content of the nodes in the documents are the same, but minor differences exist e.g. sequencing of sibling elements, values of namespace prefixes, use of implied attribute values

So using the "similar" check should give you what you want.

Edit: added prefixed attributes, same result.

Comment: The problem is in attributes prefixes. I correct my example. For nodes it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
// identical
XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(XMLUnit.compareXML(control, test), true)
// similar
XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(XMLUnit.compareXML(control, test), false)
```

Comment: The `// similar` example is wrong. It returns true when XML are different not similar.

Answer (score 0):

With XMLUnit 1.x:

```
// Similar
XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual()

// Identical
XMLAssert.assertXMLIdentical()
```

---

With XMLUnit 2.x:

```
import static org.xmlunit.assertj.XmlAssert.assertThat;
...

// Similar
assertThat(xmlResult).and(xmlExpected).areSimilar();

// Identical
assertThat(xmlResult).and(xmlExpected).areIdentical();
```

See https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit#comparing-two-documents